# Error: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-livedata

When I press the play button in Android Studio, my app compiles but is shows this error (redacted):

> Error: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations`

i am using Firebase database

Here's my app's app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
        applicationId "com.example.bye"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely, the duplicate is coming from `com.firebaseui` and needs to be excluded:

```
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0"
implementation ("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0") {
    exclude group: " android.arch.lifecycle"
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: can you tell me about this error how to solve             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/firestore/QueryListenOptions;

Answer (score 0):

When i press the cardview the app crashes

**here is my java class**

`public class CampaignActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@BindView(R.id.progress_bar)
ProgressBar progressBar;
@BindView(R.id.campaign_list)
RecyclerView friendList;

private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private FirebaseFirestore db;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;


Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_campaign);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Campaign");
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    init();
    getFriendList();


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //handle the click on the back arrow click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void init() {
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    friendList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

}


private void getFriendList() {
    Query query = db.collection("friends");

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Response> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Response>()
            .setQuery(query, Response.class)
            .build();


    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Response, FriendsHolder>(response) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder( FriendsHolder holder, int position,  Response model) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.textName.setText(model.getName());
            holder.textTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
            holder.textCompany.setText(model.getCompany());
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(model.getImage())
                    .into(holder.imageView);


        }

        @Override
        public FriendsHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup group, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.campaigncard, group, false);

            return new FriendsHolder(view);
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.name)
    TextView textName;
    @BindView(R.id.image)
    CircleImageView imageView;
    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView textTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.company)
    TextView textCompany;

    public FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

}
`
**My xml activity**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".CampaignActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/campaign_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#00000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My dependencies**

````
```apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
      javaCompileOptions {
          annotationProcessorOptions {
              includeCompileClasspath = true
          }
      }
      applicationId "com.example.bye"
      minSdkVersion 22
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
  compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
      targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
  implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.0.0"
 implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.5.0'
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
  implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:3.2.2"
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
  implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1"
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
  annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
````